# How to add textviews to a horizontalScrollView programmatically ?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to programatically add a whole bunch of textViews of a certain width and at a certain location onto a tab. Now their setX() might be placed beyond the resolution of the screen. For instance, my tab is 1240 pixels in width, and I want to place a TextView at 2000 pixels and of course have a horizontal scroll feature available. I'm essentially creating a timeline on the fly depending on the data pulled.

I'm just trying to (at the moment) get multiple TextViews thrown on to the screen, and to have the horizontal scroll view for them. I am not sure if even doing a setX(2000); will populate a TextView beyond the screen. How can I get the HorizontalScrollView to work so that I may slide my main layout to the right to see the remaining two TextViews that were created?

Some basic code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    for(int i = 50; i < 550; i+=100){
        TextView myText = new TextView(this);
        myText.setX(i * 3);
        myText.setText("HELLLLLOOOO");
        layout.addView(myText);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Turns out setX() inside a linear layout causes extremely random behavior. Inside a relative layout I can move to the desired position, but the horizontal scroller becomes disabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
            for(int i = 50; i < 550; i+=50){
                TextView myText = new TextView(this);
                myText.setX(i * 3);
                myText.setText("HELLLLLOOOO");
                sv.addView(myText);
            }
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, but unfortunately, the scroll capability is no longer active. Does me using setX() have anything to do with that?

Comment: Well adding the lines myText.setWidth(120); makes the scroll work, while myText.setWidth(80) doesn't.

Comment: Scroll is working but may be you are not getting enough TextView to scroll on device screen. for(int i = 50; i < 550; i++) Use this. And check just to debug.

Comment: I noticed, I believe you are correct in that. The reason I believed it was diabled was that I did (i = 0; i < 550; i+=50) which should result in 11 TextViews however I only had 5 that were present in the UI. I think i'll have to work on changing my plan slightly in order to make this happen. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Create one custom view for example

```
public class Example extends HorizontalScrollView {

}
```

Execute all unimplemented methods, then write this:

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(context);

TextView tv = new TextView(context);

tv.setText("Example");

tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

l.addView(tv);

addView(l);
```

Now in your xml, put the packagename and class name like this:

```
<com.argha.Example android:height and all />
```

Done, now you have HorizontalScroll view with a TextView... more text you want just do same as above.

Sorry if you found any code error, because I typed with my phone.